# How to print a Defs register using Tablegen

Tags: llvm

I have the following comparison instruction:

```
def CMPrr  : Txx32<(outs), (DataRegs:$lhs, DataRegs:$rhs),
                   "cmp $lhs, $rhs",
                   []> {
    bits<4> lhs;
    bits<4> rhs;
    let Defs = [D9];

}
```

The Instruction printer emits the following output:

```
cmp d0, d5
```

I also want to print the Defs register along with this emission. So the output should be like:

```
cmp d9, d0, d5
```

Is there a way of printing the Defs register inside the asm string? One way might be to simply write d9 inside the asm string. Is there any other way to perform this operation.

Comment: Have you found an answer for this question? I need this too.